# Javascript counter 0 to 99 set total time

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a simple javascript counter which counts 0 to 99 (code shown below). However, instead of `setTime` being the time of each number count increment, I would like to set the total time it takes to count from 0 - 99.

```js
var num = 1;

function countUp() {
  if (num > 99) {
    window.clearTimeout("setTime");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("the_count").innerHTML = num;
    num++;
    var setTime = window.setTimeout("countUp()", 1000);
  }
}
countUp();
```

```html
<div id="the_count"></div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So calculate it and change the 1000 milliseconds  to match that time...

Comment: setTime is nothing to do with time of each count increment, currently it is the timeout id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function countUp (max, time) {
  var num = 0;
  var step = time / max; // calculate the time between two steps of counting
  // create an inner function that performs one step of counting
  var fn = function () {
    num++;
    if (num <= max) {
      // if the limit is not reached, display the number ...
      document.getElementById("the_count").innerHTML = num;
      // ... and call the inner function again, some time in the future
      window.setTimeout(fn, step);
    }
  }
  
  // call the inner function for the first time
  fn();
}

countUp(100, 2000); // count up to 100 in 2000ms
```

```html
<div id="the_count"></div>
```

Comment: Couple of comments on what it does would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks PeterMader this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
function countup(start, end, time) {

  var i = start;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (++i < end) {
      document.getElementById("the_count").innerHTML = i;
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, time / (end - start));
}

countup(0, 100, 5*1000);
```

```html
<div id="the_count"></div>
```

Comment: These answers appear to be measuring how long it takes to perform the count. That was not my question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Do with `SetInterval` and `ClearInterval`

```js
var num = 1;

var setTime = setInterval(countUp, 1000)


function countUp() {
  if (num > 99) {
    window.clearInterval(setTime);
    console.log('stopped')
  } else {
    document.getElementById("the_count").innerHTML = num;
    num++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="the_count"></div>
```